Main program does not stop despite stop signal
I need your help:
I have written an image processing program that requires the screen to be on. Here is an excerpt:
# main_script.py

import time
import threading
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Event
import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from battery_monitor import monitor_low_battery_window, stop_event

directory = "C:/Users/User/pictures"

def process_files_with_work_stealing(
    main_queue: Queue,
    steal_queue: Queue,
    stop_signal: Event
) -> None:
    """Processes files using a work-stealing approach, distributing tasks between queues."""
    while not stop_signal.is_set():
        task = None

        try:
            task = main_queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            # If the main queue is empty, try to steal a task from the other queue
            try:
                task = steal_queue.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                # Both queues are empty, briefly wait before retrying
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue

        # Process file...
        pass
    
def main() -> None:
    queue_a = Queue()
    queue_b = Queue()
    stop_signal = Event()

    try:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            for folder in directory.iterdir():
                if folder.is_dir():
                    for file in folder.glob("*.png"):
                        if file.is_file():
                            if random.random() < 0.5:
                                queue_a.put(file)
                            else:
                                queue_b.put(file)

                    executor.submit(process_files_with_work_stealing, queue_a, queue_b, stop_signal)
                    executor.submit(process_files_with_work_stealing, queue_b, queue_a, stop_signal)

            # Wait until all files are processed (queues are empty)
            while not queue_a.empty() or not queue_b.empty():
                time.sleep(1)

            stop_signal.set()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nProgram interrupted by the user.")
    finally:
        stop_event.set()  # Signals the monitor thread to exit
        monitor_thread.join()  # Waits for the thread to be closed
        print("Main thread completed. Monitor thread joined.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_low_battery_window)
    monitor_thread.start()

    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nMain script interrupted and stopped.")
        stop_event.set()  # Stop the monitoring thread
        monitor_thread.join()

It is therefore important that this main program stops when the auxiliary program running in parallel detects the low battery window popping up:
# battery_monitor.py

import time
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
from colored_print import Print
import threading

stop_event = threading.Event()

def monitor_low_battery_window() -> None:
    """Monitors the screen for a low battery warning and signals the program to exit."""
    print("Monitor thread started.")
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        if check_low_battery_window(region=(900, 720, 720, 200)):  # (left, top, width, height)
            Print.critical("Low battery warning detected. Exiting program...")
            stop_event.set()
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Monitor thread exiting.")

def check_low_battery_window(region: tuple) -> bool:
    """Checks for a low battery warning window in the specified region of the screen."""
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    if region:
        left, top, width, height = region
        screenshot = screenshot[top:top + height, left:left + width]

    template = cv2.imread("low_battery_window.png")
    if template is None:
        Print.error("Low battery template image not found.")
        return False

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    locations = np.where(result >= threshold)

    return locations[0].size > 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("Starting battery monitor test...")
        monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_low_battery_window)
        monitor_thread.start()

        while not stop_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.5)

        print("Test completed. Stopping monitor thread.")

        monitor_thread.join()
        print("Monitor thread stopped successfully.")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nTest interrupted by user.")
        stop_event.set()
        monitor_thread.join()

When I run the battery_monitor.py script alone, everything works as desired. However, the main program neither stops when battery_monitor.py has detected the low-battery window nor when I trigger a keyboard interrupt.
